# Как сравнить данные в CSV файлах и удалить не повторяющиеся строки из первого?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, csv

1.csv

```
1,spain,323
3,russia,3243
4,japan,3232
5,italy,3234
6,russia,3235
7,france,3233
67,russia,3233
49,spain,543635
```

2.csv

```
spain,
russia,
japan,
Pakistan
```

Kак сравнить столбец два 1.сsv = 9000 строк и столбец один 2.csv 20 строк и удалить из файла 1.сsv стороки котрые не были найдены из столбца 2.csv? Дубли строк должны остаться в файле 1.сsv.

Вывод после обработки примера:

```
1,spain,323
3,russia,3243
4,japan,3232
6,russia,3235
67,russia,3233
49,spain,543635
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv", header=None, names=["id","name","val"])
d2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv", header=None, names=["name"])
res = d1.merge(d2)
```